# How do I rotate a moving object to focus on another moving object in GDScript?

Tags: 3d, rotation, 2d, godot

I'm trying to rotate a green ball (read player) to follow a red ball. I already stuck a camera to the green ball and it follows the green ball's rotation which is what I want. Now I need to calculate the angle and do something with a Vector2 (the ball only moves on the z,x plane). I'm currently trying to accomplish this with the following code in the green ball's script:

```
var value = 0
var player1

func _ready():
    player1 = get_transform()

func _physics_process(delta):
    var direction = player2.get_transform().origin - player1.origin
    var rotTransform = player1.looking_at(direction, Vector3(0,1,0))
    var thisRotation = Quat(Player1_t.basis).slerp(rotTransform.basis,value)

    set_transform(Transform(thisRotation, Player1_t.origin))
```

But this does not do what I thought it would. This also stops my players from being able to move around which I think comes from the set_transform also setting the position.

Could someone show me what I'm doing wrong or suggest a better solution?

Picture for more context on the result I want to have:
[CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5q7C.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a `Spatial` to look at a point, just use [`look_at`](https://godot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes/class_spatial.html#class-spatial-method-look-at):

> Rotates itself so that the local -Z axis points towards the target position.
>
> The transform will first be rotated around the given up vector, and then fully aligned to the target by a further rotation around an axis perpendicular to both the target and up vectors.
>
> Operations take place in global space.

```
extends Spatial

func _process(delta: float):
    var target = get_node("../Target").global_transform.origin
    look_at(target, Vector3.UP)
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question perfectly!